# Sortable dictionary crashes when asked to sort

Tags: swift, dictionary, jquery-ui-sortable

I decided to create my own `SortableDictionary` struct in Swift, building it in the Xcode playground so I could test it as I went. `SortableDictionary` works by taking a dictionary and a sort function and using the sort function to create a sorted array of keys from the dictionary.  It can sort by dictionary keys or by dictionary values, and has separate sorts for each (with a Bool value to toggle between the two).  I know that `findInsertionIndex` works as it is supposed to, and I'm confident of `insert` and `sort`.  But whenever I tried to create a `SortableDictionary` instance I kept getting

```
Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode-0x0)
```

no matter what I tried. After posting on hear, I found that the error only occurs when SortableDictionary has to deal with a dictionary with more than one value.  Pass it a dictionary with one or no values and it will work.  Thus this will work:

```
let collection: [String: Double] = ["Bananas": 5]
var sortedDictionary2 = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, sortByValues: true, valueSortKey: {$0 < $1}, keySortKey: {$1 < $0})

var collection: [String: Double] = ["Bananas": 5]
var sortedDictionary2 = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, sortByValues: true, valueSortKey: {$0 < $1}, keySortKey: {$1 < $0})
```

But this will not:

```
let collection: [String: Double] = ["Bananas": 5, "Dates": 3]
var sortedDictionary2 = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, sortByValues: true, valueSortKey: {$0 < $1}, keySortKey: {$1 < $0})

var collection: [String: Double] = ["Bananas": 5, "Dates": 3]
var sortedDictionary2 = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, sortByValues: true, valueSortKey: {$0 < $1}, keySortKey: {$1 < $0})
```

I then cut out sort, insert, and the two findInsertionIndex methods from the SortableDictionary struct along with all of the non calculated global variables.  This moved the error to the line in findInsertionIndex(key sorting version):

```
if (keySortKey!(sortedKeys[upperBound], key))
```

This despite the fact that sortingByValues was true which meant that function should not have ever even been called (I double checked this, sortingByValues is true at the time of the if statement, yet Xcode insists on executing the else branch instead).  So then I rewrote the code the bare minimum to switch from using global variables to parameters passed into each function.  This moved the error code to the line in insert:

```
sortedKeys = sortedKeys.filter {$0 != key}
```

The number of Key:Value pairs in the dictionary no longer appear to have any effect on the error.  I still have no idea what is going on, but I've created a Gist for my sortable dictionary and append both versions of my modified function code to the end (only use one at a time).  Here is my Sortable Dictionary code:

https://gist.github.com/7OOTnegaTerces/6277116470d03b4676c5

Comment: I'm glad you are confident of your code, but when I copy/paste your gist into a playground, I get three separate compile errors.

Comment: @DanielT. Could you be a bit more specific?  Like what and where?!? Did you import Foundation?

Comment: You use a function `round` in two places that isn't defined in the gist and you are missing a `!` in one place. I'm sure if you copy/pate your gist into a blank playground you will see the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  It was an end-case error (in coding, there are never any errors in the middle of a problem, only at its ends), I wasn't dealing properly with sorting keys into sortedKeys when first starting out (i.e when sortedKeys has zero or one members).  I fixed this, and added a sortedValues for some added features, and it all works now.  You can give it a dictionary and either a key or value sort method, or both, and it will sort create the proper sortedKeys and sortedValues arrays.  I've updated my code on Gist: https://gist.github.com/7OOTnegaTerces/6277116470d03b4676c5.

Answer (score 0):

Once I fixed the compile errors, I did the following and it worked fine:

`let dict = SortableDictionary<String, Int>(valueSortKey: { $0 < $1 })`

This also worked:

`var sortedDictionary = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, keySortKey: {$0 > $1})`

and so did this:

`var sortedDictionary = SortableDictionary(dictionary: collection, valueSortKey: {$0 < $1})`

The above two had collection declared like this:
`let collection: [String: Double] = [:]`

Comment: As I commented before, you have to import Foundation, but where was I missing a "!"?

Comment: Found "!", why didn't Xcode complain about that before?!?  Also, I always get an "Ambigous use of operator >" when try {$0 > $1}, how do you get it to accept ">"?

Comment: As I noted in my question, it appears that it only works if the dictionary has no more than one element, more and it crashes.  Any suggestions on how to make it ACTUALLY work?